# Cannot Remap CapsLock after Swapping with Ctrl

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, swap, emacs

I've remapped my caps lock key so that development in Emacs will be much faster. To do this, I edited `/etc/default/keyboard` to include:

```
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"
```

This swapped the Caps lock key with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. After some time, I realized that I would rather have both the <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys perform the same function instead of being swapped. So I changed the above to be:

```
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"
```

This should make it so Caps lock and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> act as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, right? Well, when I ran:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh console-setup
```

and rebooted, no changes were made to the mapping of the two keys. They were still swapped. So instead, I decided to revert to the normal mapping with

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Again, no changes took effect. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a solution **for X only**...

The technique I was recommended is to put the following in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
xmodmap - << !
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
!
```

You will have to run it once when you log in.

If you run it twice, it will reverse the behaviour, i.e. go back to normal again!